# ngswitch not working, scope is not right

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <h4>Correct email?</h4>
    <div ng-switch on="changeEmail" >
        <div class="row" ng-switch-default >
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <p>EMAIL</p>        
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" ng-click="changeEmail = true;">Change</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" ng-switch-when="true" >
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Enter email">
                </div>        
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" ng-click="confirmChangedEmail()">Confirm</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The controller:

```
 .controller('settingsController',function($scope, User){

    $scope.partials = {
        accounts : appPartials + "settings/accounts.html"
      , plans : appPartials + "settings/plans.html"
      , notifications : appPartials + "settings/notifications.html"
    }
    $scope.partial = $scope.partials.notifications;

    $scope.confirmChangedEmail = function () {
        // Submit email
    }
})
```

I cannot get the switch to work and when I use the angular extension, I can see that it's not in the same scope. Any ideas? I did a quick fix by putting `settings.changeEmail` and that worked, just not sure why at all?

Comment: Can you show us where you defined the scope and your controller? Also, there is no need for the semicolon in the ng-click expression

Comment: @link64 included the controller

Comment: This works http://plnkr.co/edit/xHfbt4Xgje0avCQpo3rx?p=preview and this does not http://plnkr.co/edit/lJGQaNUefUfPK5dT7UBL?p=preview

Answer (score 3):

This works http://plnkr.co/edit/xHfbt4Xgje0avCQpo3rx?p=preview and
 this does not http://plnkr.co/edit/lJGQaNUefUfPK5dT7UBL?p=preview

The reason the above does not work is the changeEmail is created in its own scope of ng-switch
Either use like the following (which uses $parent)
http://plnkr.co/edit/UOzqFLup5hdQhdqd5csZ?p=preview

or better way is to do is use model object

```
$scope.user = {};
and then use user.changeEmail
```

Answer (score 2):

`ng-switch` creates its own scope.

When you set `changeEmail` as you have done in `ng-click`, this does not modify the value of `changeEmail` you intend. If you want access to `changeEmail` inside your `ng-switch` scope, then prefix it with `$parent`, I believe that should work.

Like so:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" ng-click="$parent.changeEmail = true">Change</button>
</div>
```

Highly recommended reference: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes

Answer (score 1):

ngSwitch-when matches based on literal string values, and not expressions.

> Be aware that the attribute values to match against cannot be
>   expressions. They are interpreted as literal string values to match
>   against. For example, ng-switch-when="someVal" will match against the
>   string "someVal" not against the value of the expression
>   $scope.someVal.

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch

So, you change your ng-click to be:

```
  <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" ng-click="$parent.changeEmail = 'true'">Change</button>
```

Here is a plunkr with everything working:

http://plnkr.co/bYvY4deshw9vQ79fHjLP